# Does Aloe Vera help pass drug test?

Tags: recreational-drugs, plants

> The news which is flashing says that usage of Aloe Vera products like juice, gel or shampoo may avoid traces of drugs from the body. It is rumored that Aloe Vera consumption gets you negative for Drug abuse test, disguising the traces or could completely erase the drug concentration in the body and hence the blood samples.

https://www.chikitsa.com/aloe-vera-for-drug-test

> Asked if taking aloe vera could camouflage the traces of drugs, they said detoxification could erase traces from blood samples.

http://www.thehansindia.com/posts/index/Telangana/2017-07-26/Aloe-vera-detoxifies-drug-users/314703

> “Aloe vera, which is frequently used by sportspersons and others for passing the drug test, is much in demand in the city following the busting of the drug racket involving Tollywood celebrities. Most of the film personalities have also used expensive aloe-vera-based hair shampoos for cleaning their hair before coming to our office,” a top official, who grilled the film personalities, said.

http://www.newindianexpress.com/cities/hyderabad/2017/jul/26/film-stars-gulp-aloe-vera-to-hoodwink-sit-1633645.html

> every one of the celebraties going to before SIT are said to be drinking liters of Aloe Vera juice.According to the restorative research, if a man drinks however much liquid as could reasonably be expected couple of days preceding the drug test, exorbitant weakening in blood and urine tests will help in imperfect outcomes. Aloe Vera squeezed is observed to be far sound in detoxification of the drugs present in body.

http://alajadi.com/film-stars-using-juice-gels-escape-drugs-case/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmRCEXIJb_8

I don't know if I am allowed to post forum posts here, but there are a lot of users on forums (body building, drug forums) recommending the use of Aloe vera to pass drug tests.

Comment: Is there any explanation of the supposed method of action?  Everyone and his brother uses aloe vera shampoo.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The news is about actors and actresses using Aloe Vera based products to pass drug tests. Wait. I'll link more stuff.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Also I found people on Body building forums and drug forums recommending Aloe vera for passing drug tests.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The method of action they state is **detoxification**.

Comment: "Detoxification" isn't a "mechanism", it's a (supposed) result.

Comment: And "detox" is commonly achieved by abstaining from the drug until the effects wear off.  This appears to be what is being described in one of the articles.

Comment: According to your  "The General Physicians also stated that there is no scientific evidence which states that aloe vera juice flushes out drugs in the body. High doses of aloe latex have been linked to many serious side effects."